# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException after refactoring Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am encountering a ConflictingBeanDefiitionException saying org.company.app.core.controller.web.EquipmentController conflicts with org.company.app.core.controller.EquipmentController. The only problem is there is no org.company.app.core.controller.EquipmentController. It used to be there, I moved it to the package org.company.app.core.controller.web.

I don't understand why this is happening. Is this a weird Intellij thing or what?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'equipmentController' for bean class [org.company.app.core.controller.web.EquipmentController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.company.app.core.controller.EquipmentController]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:262)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:480)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: This sometimes happened to me as well after refactorings, not necessarily in IJ but also in Eclipse. Have you tried cleaning the output directory and rebuilding the project, either normally, `mvn clean package`, or whatever you may be using?

Comment: That did work with some extra steps, I am using Gradle with Intellij 14. I had to delete both out/ and build/ directories. I then ran gradle clean build war. After that I had to delete the .idea/ and intellij project file and re-open the project. Weird issue.

Comment: Yeah, when it first happened I was also awed. Then I figured it may have created some garbage by not removing the old class definitions somehow, hence the cleanup suggestion.

Comment: Try to invalidate cache and restart option in IDEA

Comment: invalidate cache/restart didn't work for me, but `mvn clean package` did the trick

Answer (score 3):

```
mvn clean package
```

Worked for me  . It attempts to clean the files and directories generated by Maven during its old build.